# How can I remove or hide Global Links from login screen in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM 6.5 community edition. There are "globalLinks" on Login screen.

I don't want these links `Employees, Support, About` on login page. How can i remove it from login page only?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for remove global links from header. Try with below code:

Create new file custom/Extension/application/Ext/GlobalLinks/links.php

```
if (isset($global_control_links['training']))
{
    unset($global_control_links['training']);
}

if (isset($global_control_links['employees']))
{
    unset($global_control_links['employees']);
}

if (isset($global_control_links['about']))
{
    unset($global_control_links['about']);
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to do a "quick repair and rebuild" for changes to take effect

Comment: Also +1  because this way is upgrade-safe

Answer (score 0):

Place this in custom/include/globalControlLinks.php:

```
// To add new links
$global_control_links['training'] = array(
    'linkinfo' => array($app_strings['LBL_TRAINING'] => 'index.php?module=Administration&action=ServiceCase'),
    'submenu' => ''
);

// To remove existing links
$global_control_links['about'] = array();`
```

Comment: Hi @pauel, I would like to remove only from Login page, so what is condition for that?

Comment: Normally there aren't any global links without authorization. What theme are you using? Take a look in the themes tpls/header.tpl there is a section that ensures that:       
    
    {if $AUTHENTICATED}
        <div id="header">
        {include file="_companyLogo.tpl" theme_template=true}
        {include file="_globalLinks.tpl" theme_template=true}
        {include file="_welcome.tpl" theme_template=true}
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

Comment: I am using default theme. Yes this code is inside header.tpl but i want to hide this `_globalLinks.tpl` only in login screen.

Comment: This is exactly what happens in the extract I posted. If the user is not authenticated the file doesn't get included and the login screen is shown. Please verify that the file is used by adding some letters in front of the if and inside the if block. Use developer settings or repair & rebuild, and don't forget your browsers cache sometimes holds some stuff.